# Is this a Sugar daddy Bitcoin scam or not?

Tags: scams, cryptocurrency, security, sugar-daddy

I’ve been talking to this acclaimed “sugar daddy” and I’m trying to figure out if it’s a scam. He hasn’t asked for any bank info or any other private information. He told me that my fee for receiving my allowances was to put in $200 into Bitcoin and to send him a screenshot confirming I paid the “fee”. I have no idea how Bitcoin works but is this sketchy?

Comment: What is an *acclaimed* sugar daddy, as opposed to a bog-standard sugar daddy?

Comment: Without bank info, how would you receive your allowances? In cash?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance-fee_scam

Comment: Any plan that involves you paying money to receive money is a scam.  If the incoming money were real, they'd just deduct the fees before sending it to you.

Answer (score 9):

> He told me that my fee for receiving my allowances

That's all we need to see to know that it's a scam.

(And *really*, that's **not** how the sex-for-money process works.)

Comment: Anyone who tells you that they will give you money but first you have to give them money is trying to scam you.

Comment: "Fee", "Bitcoin" and "Sugar Daddy" all had have me convinced it was a scam

Comment: And who's being scammed?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo - the OP is being scammed. In genuine sugar daddy - sugar baby relationships, the daddy pays the baby (for sex), not the other way around. The scam is what is called 'advance fee fraud' where the victim is asked to pay money first to get more later (which never comes).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey How do you know it's not about recruiting people to launder cash?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo - it probably is multipurpose, if the mark bites, you get $200 at least, and probably, therefore, they are gullible or desperate enough to be a money mule also. If you have to pay upfront, it's a scam.